# jQuery .next() and .closest() not working

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML document,

```
<strong><a href='#' class='showMore'>Show More</a></strong>
<div class='more'>This is it</div>
```

I want to show `div.more` on mouse over of `a.showMore`.

```
$("a.showMore").hover(function()
{
    $(this).closest('.more').show();

},function()
{

});
```

I still can't get the MORE box to show.
What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: @undefined - That'll probably be a paste error.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following:

```
$("a.showMore").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().next(".more").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code is not working is because you're using closest() which is traversing up the DOM, trying to get the ancestors : http://api.jquery.com/closest/

.more is the sibling of your a tag, so use this instead :

```
$("a.showMore").hover(function()
{
    $(this).siblings('.more').toggle();
});​
```

EDIT: You edited the markup after I posted that, that will work with the following markup :

```
<a href='#' class='showMore'><strong>Show More</strong></a>
<div class='more'>This is it</div>
```

Comment: Thanks jeromesmadja, this still doesn't solve it. I did a console.log and it returns a jQuery object.